# Ubuntu 16.04 can't reconnect to VPN without restarting the network manager service

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I'm a bit new to Ubuntu and Linux in general

I've 2 VPN connections (say A and B) which I use for different purposes. When I disconnect from vpn A I can't reconnect (to A again) nor can I connect to vpn B unless I restart the network manager service.

I use Ubuntu 16.04
OpenVPN 2.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the problem on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) and Raymond Berger has [confirmed the issue that affects the version 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 of the network-manager package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1675199) .

Here is a solution to downgrade to the previous version of network-manager (1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4). This has solved the problem for me.

1. `sudo apt policy network-manager`
    (you should see the available versions of network-manager)
2. `sudo apt install network-manager=1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`
    (replace by the suited version, this one works for me)
3. `sudo apt-mark hold network-manager`
    (this will prevent the update of your network-manage package)

If you want to unhold :

4. `sudo apt-mark showhold`
    (you should see network-manager)
5. `sudo apt-mark unhold network-manager`